# Oracle Apex date column throwing validation error without validation set

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an IG with 2 columns.

First is Employee_Name which is text.

I have another column which is date column with simple datatype as date.
Normally when i click save button, it inserts/updates the entries successfully in the database table.

But as soon as i added a validation on EMPLOYEE_NAME as not null, if i change date for the row it throws invalid date error upon saving.

This did not throw error when there was no validation on employee_name field.

How can these be related?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider NOT to create your own validation for something that Apex offers in item's properties, and it is called **Value required**? Just turn it ON.

---

As of your question: did you run the page in debug mode to check what's really going on?

Answer (score 0):

What is your validation **type** ?
and instead of using validation , did you make `Employee_Name` as **NOT NULL** column ?

Comment: Currently it is not an answer, it is attempt to clarify the question. For this purpose comments are used on SO